# How to change the starting Activity?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I can't change the starting Activity. I do some research on google but I don't find one about Java IntelliJ. It is like in the `AndroidManifest` in Android Studio but this in Java IntelliJ.

I'm trying to find any solution but I can't find one.

In Android Studio it's like this, but I don't know how to do that in Java IntelliJ.

```
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: the "starting screen activity"? are we talking about the startup screen of your application? or of the IDE? IntelliJ doesn't care, it 'll show exactly what you program it to show. if you mean of your IDE, don't.

Comment: im talking about my startup screen of my application . its like when i want to change the starting screen from **LOGIN Activity** to **REGISTER Activity**

Comment: and ... you assume the behavior of your application depends on which IDE it is developed in, rather than the code?

Comment: Android Studio is just a customized version of IntelliJ IDEA, so things should work the same.

Comment: It works the same in Eclipse as well (by using the `AndroidManifest` file).

Answer (score 0):

If you have created an Android project, then you should have an AndroidManifest.xml file, regardless of whether you're using IntelliJ or Android Studio. Take a look at the official page for creating an android project in IntelliJ (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-a-new-android-project.html), there you will see that the default project structure contains the AndroidManifest.xml. If you don't have it in your project, I would suggest trying to create the project again.